# При скролле не плавает правое меню

Tags: css3, javascript, html

Где добавить display:block; чтобы когда делаю скролл плавал правый меню?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>   <style> .lf{width:960px;margin:0
 auto;background-color:#F3F3F3;}
 </style> <style> .lp{   
 margin-bottom:100px;
         margin-right:50px;
         margin-left:50px;} </style> <style>
 body{background-image:url(../apple.jpg);}
 </style> <style> .lp{padding-top:50px;
 padding-bottom:50px;} </style> <style>
 .po{margin-left:50px;} </style>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
      body, html {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;

          font-family: helvetica;
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .container {
          position: relative;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          left: 0;
          -webkit-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
          transition:  left 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }
      .container.open-sidebar {
          left: 240px;

      }

      .swipe-area {
          position: absolute;
          width: 50px;
          left: 0;
      top: 0;
          height: 100%;
          background: #f3f3f3;
          z-index: 0;
      }
      #sidebar {
          background: #DF314D;
          position: absolute;
          width: 240px;
          height: 100%;
          left: -240px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      #sidebar ul {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          list-style: none;
      }
      #sidebar ul li {
          margin: 0;
      }
      #sidebar ul li a {
          padding: 15px 20px;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 100;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #C9223D;
          -webkit-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
      }
      #sidebar ul li:hover a {
          background: #C9223D;
      }
      .main-content {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          padding: 10px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          position: relative;
      }
      .main-content .content{
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      padding-left: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      }
      .main-content .content h1{
          font-weight: 100;
      }
      .main-content .content p{
          width: 100%;
          line-height: 160%;
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle {
          background: #DF314D;
          border-radius: 3px;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          padding: 10px 7px;
          float: left;
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar{
           display: block;
          width: 18px;
          margin-bottom: 3px;
          height: 2px;
          background-color: #fff;
          border-radius: 1px;   
      }
      .main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child{
           margin-bottom: 0;   
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function(){
        $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
          var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
          $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
        });
         $(".swipe-area").swipe({
              swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
                  {
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="right") {
                           $(".container").addClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                      if (phase=="move" && direction =="left") {
                           $(".container").removeClass("open-sidebar");
                           return false;
                      }
                  }
          }); 
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="../iphonevshtc.html">Iphone VS HTC</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
          <div class="swipe-area"></div>
          <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="content">
              <h1>Сравним смартфоны iPhone 5S и HTC One</h1>
              <p><img src='../Images/Iphonevshtc/HTC-One-vs-Apple-iPhone-5S-Title.jpg'></p>
<p>Главной особенностью нового топового iPhone для нас, гиков, стал даже не сканер отпечатков пальцев (эта функция интересна как раз рядовым пользователям), а 64-разрядный процессор Apple A7. Компания из Купертино первой решилась переходить на новую архитектуру, обогнав конкурентов и сделав огромный рывок в производительности. Истинность этого предположения проще всего проверить сравнением свежайшего iPhone 5S с вышедшим в начале этого года HTC One.</p>
<BR>
<p>Установленный в iPhone 5S Apple A7 представляет из себя двухъядерный 64-bit ARMv8 чип с частотой 1.3 ГГц и ускорителем PowerVR G6430. Противостоять ему будет 32-bit ARMv7 процессор Qualcomm Snapdragon 600 с четырьмя ядрами Krait 300, частота которых может достигать 1.7 ГГц. В чип также встроен ускоритель Adreno 320. Конечно, серьезно на результаты тестов будет влиять и программное обеспечение: в iPhone установлена iOS 7.0.1 с полной поддержкой 64-разрядных процессоров, а тестовый  HTC One оснащен лишь Android 4.1.2, так как операторская модификация AT&T еще не получила обновление. Но вряд ли не совсем свежая версия ОС серьезно повлияет на результаты.</p>
<img src="../Images/Iphonevshtc/HTC-One-vs-Apple-iPhone-5S-Geekbench.jpg">
<p>Первым полем для сражения стал кросс-платформенный набор тестов Geekbench 3. Новый смартфон Apple набрал 1 415 баллов в одноядерном режиме и 2 565 — в многоядерном, HTC One же может похвастаться лишь 622 и 1 843 баллами соответственно. Несмотря на такой перевес на стороне iPhone 5S, подробный разбор тестирования показал, что с несколькими операциями Snapdrgon 600 и Android справились быстрее.
</p>
<img src="../Images/Iphonevshtc/HTC-One-vs-Apple-iPhone-5S-3DMark.jpg">
<p>Далее смартфоны протестировали в 3DMark от Futuremark — компании, «собаку съевшей» на создании бенчмарков. И здесь iPhone 5S по итоговым показателям оказался производительнее конкурента — 13 291 против 10 293 баллов. Однако с обсчетом физики процессор HTC One справляется существенно лучше —  в этом тесте он набрал 12 468 баллов и показал средний результат в 39.6 кадров в секунду. Аналогичные показатели Apple iPhone 5S таковы — 7 125 баллов и 22.6 fps.</p>
<img src="../Images/Iphonevshtc/HTC-One-vs-Apple-iPhone-5S-PassBench-System.jpg">
<br>
<br>
<img src="../Images/Iphonevshtc/HTC-One-vs-Apple-iPhone-5S-PassBench-CPU.jpg">
<p>И PassMark PerformanceTest показал уже ожидаемое преимущество Apple iPhone 5S — общая оценка смартфона составила 5 454 балла, тогда как HTC One получил лишь 3 096 баллов. При тестировании процессорных ядер более современная архитектура дала о себе знать — 35 380 и 9 169 баллов. 64-разрядный процессор, даже с меньшей частотой и количеством ядер, в разы быстрее проводит вычисления как с фиксированной, так и с плавающей точкой.</p>
<img src="../Images/Iphonevshtc/HTC-One-vs-Apple-iPhone-5S-PassBench-Memory.jpg">
<p>Скорость работы iPhone 5S со встроенной памятью оценена утилитой от PassMark в 23 621 балл, а у One — 6 816 баллов. Не такой существенный, но все равно большой разрыв и в скорости работы смартфонов с ОЗУ: HTC One получил 2 905, а смартфон Apple — 5 339 баллов.</p>
<img src="../Images/Iphonevshtc/HTC-One-vs-Apple-iPhone-5S-PassBench-Graphics.jpg">
<p>В двухмерной графике Qualcomm Snapdragon 600 и Adreno 320 лишь немного проигрывают Apple A7 и PowerVR G6430 — 2 492 и 2 168 баллов соответственно. А вот в 3D iPhone с 1 938 баллами существенно обходит One с 1 099 баллами.</p>
<img src="../Images/Iphonevshtc/HTC-One-vs-Apple-iPhone-5S-GFXBench.jpg">
<p>Последним в сравнении Apple iPhone 5S и HTC One поучаствовал тест T-Rex HD, входящий в состав GFXBench 2.7. Результаты HTC One в onscreen и offscreen вариантах практически идентичны, разрешение экрана совпадает с заданным разрешением теста. Возьмем меньший результат, 806 кадров со средней скоростью 14 кадров в секунду. 2 031 кадр в onscreen-тесте при 36 fps и 1 371 кадр в offscreen-тесте при среднем значении 24 кадра в секунду — впечатляющие показатели iPhone 5S. Сравнение результатов offscreen-тестов показывает превосходство смартфона Apple.
<br>
Новый смартфон от Apple и встроенный в него 64-разрядный процессор серьезно превосходят конкурентов в синтетических тестах. Имеет ли смысл такое наращивание мощности при сегодняшней достаточной скорости работы — каждый решает для себя сам.</p> 
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @grigor, сделайте что-нибудь с примером, я честно пытался его портировать на jsfiddle, но там происходит буквально ничего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/Md5CQ/1/)**

1) Поправить html верстку.

```
<div class="fixed-cell"> <!-- Оборачиваем div.swipe-area в новый блок -->
   <div class="swipe-area">
      <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle"> <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span></a>    
   </div>
</div> <!-- Конец обертки. -->
```

2) Поправить стили.

```
/* В самый конец добавляем такие стили: */
.fixed-cell {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
```